# way of measuring branch prediction hit rate

Tags: c, performance, winapi, caching, profiling

I am writing C procedures under `winapi`.

Is there some convenient way of measuring "branch prediction
hit rate" for chosen procedure/loop ? Especialy
compiler agnostic and reliable way (I mean with
reliable results not spoiled by something).

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool from valgrind (Cachegrind: a cache and branch-prediction profiler):
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html

Also be aware of this article:
[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array#11227902)